# ios objc - Memory leak in CGImageDestinationFinalize when creating gif

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I'm saving images to the document directory and saving the path in core data.

I'm then querying core data for all of these paths and attempting to make a gif out of these images.

I'm getting a huge memory leak in CGImageDestinationFinalize and have been stuck for the past hour with no idea as to how to proceed.

Any advice would be appreciated.

I have checked out this link with the same exact question but as it has no valid answers, I'm posting my own:
[Creating a large GIF with CGImageDestinationFinalize - running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723024/creating-a-large-gif-with-cgimagedestinationfinalize-running-out-of-memory)

[image]

**Edit - ** I have uploaded the project that I made to test this before implementing it in my application. This is the exact project where I'm having this issue. Anyone care to take a look? thank you
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbtpdpp2uaf4pj0/BugTester.zip?dl=0

Comment: Actually goes up to 1 gb memory consumption if I leave it.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue :(